# Download file from WebAPI to angular 6 app

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular6

I have web App in angular 6 with .NET webApi (.NET 4.5 framework).

What I am doing is collecting some user input, sending a request to webapi.
Webapi generate a excel file (xlsx or xlsm) with some data from db.
Now i need to download this file on user machine.
I have verified on server, generated file is correct and created at temp directory on server.
but it is downloading as corrupted file on user machine and Excel is unable to open it.

Any idea how can I fix this.

WebApi code

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
        public ActionResult Put(Parameters inputs)
        {
            var path = GenerateFile(inputs);
            string extension = new FileInfo(path).Extension;
            switch (extension)
            {
               case ".xls":
                    return new FilePathResult(path, "application/msexcel");
                case ".xlsx":
                    return new FilePathResult(path, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                case ".xlsm":
                    return new FilePathResult(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12");

            }
        }
```

Angular code:

```
GenerateReprot() {
    this.http.put(this.webApiURL, this.Input, 'arraybuffer')
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.downLoadFile(result, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
          alert('file downloaded successfully. ');
        },
        error => {
          alert('error with downloading file.');
        }
      );
  }

    downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var pwa = window.open(url);
    if (!pwa || pwa.closed || typeof pwa.closed == 'undefined') {
      alert('Please disable your Pop-up blocker and try again.');
    }
  }
```

Comment: As far as I can see in docs the ``put`` method have ``object`` as the third argument and it contains property ``responseType`` which actually should have **arraybuffer** in your case - maybe there is a problem?

Comment: I already specified third args as arraybuffer
this.http.put(this.webApiURL, this.Input, 'arraybuffer')

Comment: But you specified it in wrong way. Maybe this will help you - https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data but in your case there is also body.

Comment: @Abhash786 Confirm the platform version being used. Web API 2+ or Core? You tag shows asp.net-web-api and you show `System.Web.Http` namespace, but there is no `ActionResult` used by that framework. Most likely you are return the wrong model type and it is being serialized to JSON which is why the file readers see them as being corrupt.

Comment: @Abhash786 What does the downloaded data look like in the client?

Comment: I am using web API 2 (API controller).
on client, only 1KB file is downloaded but the actual size of was is around 30 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tag shows [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) and you show `System.Web.Http` namespace, but there is no `ActionResult` used by that framework. So it looks like you are mixing frameworks between MVC and Web API

Most likely you are returning the wrong model type and it is being serialized to JSON which is why the file readers see them as being corrupt.

The following assumes that it is being invoked in an `ApiController`

```cs
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult Put(Parameters inputs) {
    var path = GenerateFile(inputs);
    var file = new FileInfo(path);
    string contentType = null;
    switch (file.Extension) {
        case ".xls":
            contentType = "application/msexcel";
        case ".xlsx":
            contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        case ".xlsm":
            contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12";
    }

    var stream = file.OpenRead();

    var content = new StreamContent(stream);
    content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length; 
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
    content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") {
        FileName = file.Name
    };

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = content;
    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nkosi.... This is working as expected but the issue still persists.
at client side, in angular app, corrupted file downloaded with size of 1KB only.

Comment: @Abhash786 Step through the code while debugging and check the size of the stream to confirm that the data is being loaded correctly.

Comment: Stream has all the data... it is angular which is causing the issue here.

Comment: @Abhash786 Then take the content type from the response when opening the file on the client. Right now the code you have has the type hard-coded.

Comment: I solved the issue with bit of trick. again there was no issue with webapi code... it was issue with how angular downloaded the file. To do that, I had to break down the webapi call into two part, one for file creation and one for file download. I am adding my code also.
Again thanks a lot for fixing my webapi issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try `responseType: "blob"` in your HTTP put request.

```
this.http.put(this.webApiURL, this.Input, { responseType: "blob" })
  .subscribe(
...
);
```

Comment: tried the same but it is giving me run time error like response type is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Angular has some strange issues with downloading the file. With only put request, I couldn't downloaded the file. I had to break down the request into two parts
1. put request for file prepration
2. get request for file download

with only put request, it always download 1KB corrupted file.
in Angular, You also don't need to use any arraybuffer or blob. They also cause some strange issues.

here is the code (webapi)

```
[HttpPut]
        public string Put(Parameters inputs)
        {
            var file = GenerateFile(inputs);
            return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id) //id is file name returned from above put request
        {
            var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var fullPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), id + ".xlsx");

            if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                fullPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), id + ".xlsm");

                if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
                    throw new FileNotFoundException(id);
            }
            var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath));
            result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

            switch (Path.GetExtension(fullPath))
            {
                case ".xls":
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/msexcel");
                    break;
                case ".xlsx":
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                    break;
                case ".xlsm":
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12");
                    break;
            }

            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath)
            };

            return result;
        }
```

Angular Code:

```
GenerateReprot() {

    this.http.put(this.webApiURL, this.Input)
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          var url = this.webApiURL + result.json();
          window.open(url)

          alert('file downloaded successfully: ');

        }),
      error => {
        alert('error while downloading file');
      };
  }
```